# Overlaying an image upon an image

Tags: python

> Implement the function tree that takes a number of slices n and a rune as arguments,
>   and generates a stack of runes scaled and overlayed on top of each other.
>
> For example, the following command tree(4, circle_bb) should produce the following
>   depth map:
>
> The generated tree must satisfy a few properties: the circle bb at the top of the tree is
>   scaled to 1=4 of its original size (the tree has 4 layers); the next lower layer is scaled by
>   2=4, and so on. Note that the bottom-most layer retains its original size. The different
>   levels of the tree must also be spaced evenly apart.

The overlay_frac( ratio, pattern1, pattern2) and scale( size, pattern) commands, are to be used.

For the overlay_frac , this parameter determines
the fraction of the depth range occupies by the first rune; the remainder of the
depth range will be occupied by the second rune.

My code for specifically show(tree(4, circle_bb)) is :

```
def tree(n, rune):
    a= scale( 1/n, rune)
    b = scale( 2/n, rune)
    c = scale( 3/n, rune)
    Bottom = overlay_frac( 1/2, c,d)
    Middle = overlay_frac(1/2, b, Bottom)
    Top = overlay_frac(1/2, a, Middle)

    return Top
```

But I need to change into a loop so I'm writting:

```
def tree(n ,rune):
    SUM = rune
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        layer_i = scale(i/n, rune)
        SUM = overlay_frac(1/i, layer_i, SUM)
        return SUM
```

However, the image it gives is different. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Different in what way(s)?

Comment: Instead of getting layers of circle getting bigger and bigger, my loop returns just the smallest circle. It should be like a inverted cone spiral, where the top is the smallest circle and the bottom is the biggetst.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `return` statement inside of the loop, so it exits after the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def tree(n, rune):
    for i in range(n, 0, -1):
        if i == n:
            bottom = scale(i/n, rune)

        elif i < n:
            top = scale(i/n, rune)
            bottom = overlay_frac(1/i, top, bottom)
    return bottom
```

Comment: Please try to provide some description for further details.